# Nokia Lumia 520 freezes on boot

Tags: lumia

My Nokia Lumia 520 powers up, but freezes on the "Nokia" logo. I've tried a hard reset but nothing changed.

Comment: Sounds like you need to take it to a service centre and get it checked out.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the [Lumia Software Recovery Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987) to reinstall Windows Phone OS. (All your data will be gone, but I guess it's lost anyway.)

If this does not help you will need to have it repaired or replaced at a service center.

Comment: Do you know if there is an equivalent for HTC Windows Phones?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not. You'll have to get your phone to a service center for this.